# C - Static char array vs dynamic char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic, static

This code compiles with a warning but prints the input string:

```
char staticArray[100];
scanf("%s",&staticArray);
printf("%s\n", staticArray);
```

*Warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat]*

This code also compiles with a warning but throws segmentation fault:

```
char* dynamicArray;
dynamicArray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
scanf("%s", &dynamicArray);
printf("%s\n", dynamicArray);
```

*Warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]*

I know both are wrong but, why does the first one prints the string value?

Comment: For the warning in the second example, the issue is that you are getting the pointer of `dynamicArray` which is already a pointer. Removing the `&` will fix the warning.

Comment: The warning is because you passed the wrong type to`scanf`.  It wants a `char *` but you passed a `char (*)[100]` instead.  Exactly as it told you.  Fix it by removing the `&`, i.e. `scanf("%s", staticArray);`  Remember, C arrays "decay" into pointers in many contexts, including being passed as function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *why does the first one prints the string value whereas second give segfault?*

***What's happening in Case I:***

The type of `staticArray` is `char [100]` i.e. array of `100` `char`.
The type of `&staticArray` is `char (*)[100]`.
The `%s` format specifier in `scanf()` expect the argument as a pointer to initial element of `char` array i.e. of type `char *`.

You are passing `char (*)[100]` type to `scanf()`, hence compiler is giving warning on this statement.

The `&staticArray` give you pointer to the array of type `char (*)[100]` which is **numerically** same as the base address of array.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char staticArray[100];

    printf ("staticArray: %p\n", (void*)staticArray);
    printf ("&staticArray : %p\n", (void*)&staticArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
## ./a.out
staticArray: 0x7ffee4044a70
&staticArray : 0x7ffee4044a70
```

`staticArray` and `&staticArray` **both yield a pointer to the same address<sup>1)</sup> but their type is different**.
That's why when you pass `&staticArray` to `scanf()`, getting warning during compilation due to type mismatch but when `scanf()` called, it treat that pointer as `char *` and read input and store the result to given location. When printing it later, it prints the string value.

***What's happening in Case II:***

The type of `dynamicArray` is `char *`.
The type of `&dynamicArray` is `char **`.
So, you are passing `char **` type to `scanf()` which expects `char *` when `%s` format specifier is used. Hence compiler is giving warning on this statement.
The pointer `&dynamicArray` is different from `dynamicArray`.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    if (dynamicArray == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("dynamicArray: %p\n", (void*)dynamicArray);
    printf ("&dynamicArray : %p\n", (void*)&dynamicArray);

    free(dynamicArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
## ./a.out
dynamicArray: 0x7fd615401690
&dynamicArray : 0x7ffee7ab7ad0
```

`dynamicArray` and `&dynamicArray` both **yield different pointer**.

When you pass `&dynamicArray` to `scanf()` (*which read input and store the result to given location*), it lead to undefined behavior<sup>2)</sup> because your program end up accessing invalid memory.

When you pass `&dynamicArray` to `printf()` with format specifier `%s`, `printf()`, it access that address to write the character string and end up accessing invalid memory, lead to undefined behavior<sup>2)</sup>. Hence, you are getting segfault.

---

1) An array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element but there are few exceptions to this rule (C11 Standards#6.3.2.1p3):

- The array is the operand of `sizeof` operator.
- The array is the operand of `_Alignof` operator.
- The array is the operand of `&`.
- The array is a string literal used to initialize an array.

2) An [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `&` operator in both examples will solve the warnings. I'm not sure what your intended behavior is, but they seem to work correctly upon moving the `&` operator. This is because arrays are inherently pointers to the first element of the array so adding `&` is not what you want.

Working examples(exactly the same expect for `&`):

```
char staticArray[100];
scanf("%s",staticArray);
printf("%s\n", staticArray);
```

and

```
char* dynamicArray;
dynamicArray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
scanf("%s", dynamicArray);
printf("%s\n", dynamicArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it works correctly without the & operator. I was asking for the different behavior when passing a pointer to a static array. I was expecting a segmentation fault but it printed some value. H.S. answer explains why.